# (pandas) Fill NaN based on groupby and column condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Using 'bfill' or 'ffill' on a groupby element is trivial, but what if you need to fill the na with a specific value in a second column, based on a condition in a third column?

For example:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['01/10/2017', '02/09/2017', '02/10/2016','01/10/2017', '01/11/2017', '02/10/2016'], 'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'b':[4,np.nan,6, 5, np.nan, 7]})
>>> df
   a    b        date
0  1  4.0  01/10/2017
1  1  NaN  02/09/2017
2  1  6.0  02/10/2016
3  2  5.0  01/10/2017
4  2  NaN  01/11/2017
5  2  7.0  02/10/2016
```

I need to group by column 'a', and fill the NaN with the column 'b' value where the date for that row is closest to the date in the NaN row.

So the output should look like:

```
   a    b        date
0  1  4.0  01/10/2017
1  1  6.0  02/09/2017
2  1  6.0  02/10/2016
3  2  5.0  01/10/2017
4  2  5.0  01/11/2017
5  2  7.0  02/10/2016
```

Assume there is a closest_date() function that takes the NaN date and the list of other dates in that group, and returns the closest date.

I'm trying to find a clean solution that doesn't have to iterate through rows, ideally able to use apply() with lambdas. Any ideas?

Comment: Your data seems to be incorrect.  For group `a == 1` you've chosen `6` to fill in the `nan`.  However, it appears that `01/10/2017` is closer to `02/09/2017`, implying that `4` should have been the fill value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df['closest_date_by_a'] = df.groupby('a')['date'].apply(closest_date)
df['b'] = df.groupby(['a', 'closest_date_by_a'])['b'].ffill().bfill()
```

Given a function (`closest_date()`), you need to apply that function by group so it calculates the closest dates for rows within each group.  Then you can group by both the main grouping column (`a`) and the closest date column (`closest_date_by_a`) and perform your filling.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `date` column are in fact dates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': ['01/10/2017', '02/09/2017', '02/10/2016','01/10/2017', '01/11/2017', '02/10/2016'],
     'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'b':[4,np.nan,6, 5, np.nan, 7]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

print(df)

   a    b       date
0  1  4.0 2017-01-10
1  1  NaN 2017-02-09
2  1  6.0 2016-02-10
3  2  5.0 2017-01-10
4  2  NaN 2017-01-11
5  2  7.0 2016-02-10
```

---

Use `reindex` with `method='nearest'` after having `dropna()`

```
def fill_with_nearest(df):
    s = df.set_index('date').b
    s = s.dropna().reindex(s.index, method='nearest')
    s.index = df.index
    return s

df.loc[df.b.isnull(), 'b'] = df.groupby('a').apply(fill_with_nearest).reset_index(0, drop=True)

print(df)

   a    b       date
0  1  4.0 2017-01-10
1  1  4.0 2017-02-09
2  1  6.0 2016-02-10
3  2  5.0 2017-01-10
4  2  5.0 2017-01-11
5  2  7.0 2016-02-10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about the 'nearest' fill method, that's pretty neat.

I'm trying this method on my data and it works for a few iterations then gives an error: `ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit`

Have any idea what would cause this? I've tried to recreate the error on the example by adding new rows with the same 'date' values, but it still works fine.